# Rectangle getting bigger instead of changing position

Tags: java, cube

on another program I've been having the same problem, so I gave you what I'm trying to do with a smaller class so you can read the code more easily.
Basically, I'm trying to change the X position, however it seems to be just getting bigger.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;


public class test extends JPanel{

    public int x = 200;
    public int y = 620;

    Rectangle cube = new Rectangle(x, y, 80, 80);

    int cubex = cube.x;


    public void paint(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.fill(cube);

    }

    public void moveCube(){
        cube.setLocation(cubex -= 1, y);
        cube.setSize(80, 80);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        test t = new test();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.add(t);

        frame.setSize(700, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("The Cube");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setBackground(new Color(240, 84, 84));

        while(true){

            t.moveCube();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your programm. You are moving the object correctly, yet your are not clearing your previously painted rectangle; thus it seems as it is expanding.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do this? I'm really new to this :)